# Go realtime application heavy writes on ResponseWriter

Tags: web-applications, go, websocket, webserver, real-time

I have a web application that needs to keep writing (possibly never ending) to`http.ResponseWriter`, and to display those output to html page. It's something like:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
     switch req.Method {
         case "GET":
              for {
                  fmt.Fprintln(w, "repeating...")
              }
     }
}
```

I feel like the HTML output does not catch up fast enough.

If I want to keep writing on `http.ResponseWriter` and display those on HTML as fast as possible in realtime, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: That could either be implemented via [websocket](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket#example-Handler) or GOA (Good ol' AJAX). Either way, you simply append the new data to the old.

Comment: stream can over http, but js with browser can not process http partly-received response, so websocket or make http request again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [http.ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) uses a [bufio.ReadWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ReadWriter) for the underlying connection, which buffers all writes. You have to flush the buffer after every write, if you want your data to be sent as fast as possible.

There is a [http.Flusher](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher) interface for this in the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http) package, that is implemented by the default [http.ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

With this you could rewrite your example as follows:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
     switch req.Method {
     case "GET":
          for {
              fmt.Fprintln(w, "repeating...")

              if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
                  f.Flush()
              }
          }
     }
}
```

This will flush the internal buffer after every write.